# How can I get the data from my Survey123 form using Python

Tags: python, download, arcgis

I am trying to access my ESRI Survey123 results that aren't Everyone(public) accessible. I'm using the `arcgis` Python package on a machine that does not have ArcGIS installed. Unfortunately, I can only access public results in my account (and elsewhere). How can I retrieve the data when it's not public

*Additional information:* the survey was created without using any existing ESRI features, layers, or other stuff - just opened Survey123 online and created the survey

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS

# ESRI Survey123 API endpoint
survey123_api_url = 'https://www.arcgis.com'
survey123_username = '<my_username>'
survey123_password = '<my_password>'

# Get a list of non-public Survey123 data
survey_item_id = '88d7e11f82fa44c0a52db4ba435b86ff' # A random ID 
gis = GIS(survey123_api_url, survey123_username, survey123_password)

# Use SurveyManager to see everything available
survey_manager = arcgis.apps.survey123.SurveyManager(gis)
print(survey_manager.surveys) # only contains public items

# Try to get a non-public item
sbi = survey_manager.get(survey_item_id)
print(sbi) # only contains item when it's public

sr = gis.content.search('owner:<my account name>')
print(sr)   # also only contains public items
```

Note: [original post](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/access-non-public-results-from-survey123-outside/m-p/1305982/thread-id/68094#M68202) in ESRI community

Answer (score 1):

Don't go through SurveyManager to access to your data. Perform a search on the connection and filter the results to find the layer and then the feature(s) you are looking for (Features contain the data)

*See below for related ESRI links*

First, create the connection to ESRI

```py
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS

# Connect to ArcGIS (use the URI to your own server if not using AGOL)
gis = GIS('https://www.arcgis.com',<username>, <password>)
```

Get everything you are the owner of and look through the results for the layer your are interested in

```py
# Search for accessible content
search_results = gis.content.search('owner:<username>')

# Look for the layer we're interested in
for one_search in search_results:
    # Find the feature service that you are looking for
    # It is simple in this case since there is only one Feature Service - you may need
    # to add additional filters
    if one_search.type == 'Feature Service':
        # Choose the layer
        feature_layer = one_search.layers[0]
```

Finally query the layer to get the data we want. We're using the `OBJECTID` to grab everything. You can find the names of fields to filter on by looking at your survey results online in AGOL

```py
        # Perform a query to get all of the data
        results = feature_layer.query(where='OBJECTID>=0')

        # Process the returned data (printing in this case)
        for data in results.features:
            print(data.as_dict)
```

**Here is the completed script**

```py
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS

# ESRI endpoint
esri_url = 'https://www.arcgis.com'
esri_username = '<username>'
esri_password = '<password>'

# Connect to ArcGIS
gis = GIS(esri_url, esri_username, esri_password)

# Search for accessible content
search_results = gis.content.search('owner:<username>')
for one_search in search_results:
    # Find the feature service that you are looking for
    if one_search.type == 'Feature Service':
        # Choose the layer
        feature_layer = one_search.layers[0]
        # Perform a query to get all of the data
        results = feature_layer.query(where='OBJECTID>=0')
        # Process the returned data (printing in this case)
        for data in results.features:
            print(data.as_dict)
```

Here's some links I found useful:
Python API: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/

Features API documentation: https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html

Python examples: https://developers.arcgis.com/survey123/guide/python-samples/

Python example Notebooks: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/tree/20e971a2e300a33805c1ddd5223008eee90c49af/guide